# Persisting multiple things a single command handler with CQRS

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm trying to apply CQRS+ES to my pet project. But I'm not sure how to handle complex commands.

Suppose I have a web page where you can create a new `User`. So on that you page you simply enter *firstname, lastname, username and password*. But, you ***must*** also add one or more `Role`s to that user. When hitting the ***Save*** button then the following command is fired `CreateUserWithRolesCommand`.

Is the following a valid approach in a command handler?

```
public class CreateUserWithRolesCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUserWithRolesCommand>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public UserCommandHandler(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
        // todo: begin db transaction 

        var user = new User();
        user.Username = command.Username;
        user.Password = command.Password;
        user.Firstname = command.Firstname;
        user.Lastname = command.Lastname;
        _context.User.Add(user);
        _context.Save();

        // After save, get user id
        van userId = user.Id;

        van userRoles = new UserRoles;

        // Ommiting foreach loop and just taking the 
        // first role to keep the example simpler
        userRole.RoleId = command.Roles.First().RoleId;
        userRole.UserId = userId;
        _context.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
        _context.Save();

        // end db transaction and commit if all successful
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that I see is thee anemic domain model. You have only setters, this is not OK. Replace all the setters with a command method. In this case you should have only a `User.create(usename, password, firstName, lastName)` method that returns void.

Secondly, there are two Aggregates so you need to have two transactions. In your code you have only one transaction. Remember that [Aggregates are the largest transactional boundary](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html).

But then you take into consideration that something bad can (and will) happen before the second transaction (the role is added to user). For example, the server is restarted or crashes just after the user is added to the repository. After it restarts it won't have enough information to continue the *process* of adding user roles.

A solution would be to model it as a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx). You will have a CreateUserWithRoles entity that is created with all the needed information. In this case the content of the CreateUserCommand is enough. Then, you need to add a `progress` state variable, i.e. an Enum (Started, UserCreated and RoleAdded)  that will  *remember* the last performed state and/or you make the User.create and UserRoles.add idempotent. After you create the  CreateUserWithRoles entity you `run` it. The `run` method jump over the performed steps by looking at the `progress` and performs the remaining steps. In this way, if something bad happens (it will, trust me) the Saga can be resumed.

You will also need a way to detect all the Sagas that are in a stopped state and resume them (by executing their `run` method).

*PS: I use the term "transaction" to express the fact that an operation must be done in an atomic mode (all or nothing) but a scalable Event store implementation should not use database transactions at all.*

Comment: Indeed with Constantin about how to handle eventual consistency. However I think is overkill for this specific scenario "CreateUserWithRole" and using ES. My proposal is just publish to events to the same event stream (userId), one is "UserRegistered" and the other "RolesAdded". This two events are save into the event store in the same transaction.

Comment: @martinezdelariva I used the term "transaction" but I don't necessarily mean DB transaction. In ES one could use transactionless persistence (for better performance and scalability). But this is possible only for a single stream. Two Aggregates have 2 streams so it can not be done inside a single "transaction"

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine in a command handler.  However, it appears as though you are using data-oriented classes (perhaps entity framework).  Your domain model would typically map from any data storage mechanism (even an ORM, unless your ORM has the ability to use the domain model directly).  I try to avoid ORMs.  The next thing is that CQRS isn't *really* in the picture yet.  This also doesn't qualify as event sourcing since your aggregates are not constituted from events.

I have a work-in-progress (as at 7 Feb 2018) that deals with *Identity & Access Control* called [Shuttle.Access](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Access) that makes use of my [Shuttle.Recall](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Recall) event sourcing mechanism.  The [domain source](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Access/tree/master/Shuttle.Access/Domain) may give you some ideas.

Your basic design seems sound.  A *User* aggregate with a number of attached *UserRole* value objects.